# Click button raises error no such element

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click on a button using selenium in VBA and I set this line

```
Set ele = .FindElementByXPath("//div/button[@ng-click='VerifyData()']")
```

On the webpage, I can find this XPath and it is correct but when trying it in the code, I got an error No Such Element
I have searched for iframe in the HTML page but no clue

```html
<div class="form-details">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <a style="color: #ea3c00; font-size: 20px;" class="float-right back-button" ng-click="BackToHome()"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> </a>
                        <h5>
                             
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group form-item">
                        <label for=""><span> أدخل   </span>&nbsp; <span style="font-size:.7em;" ng-show="EmailType == 1" class=""></span></label>
                        <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control number ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" maxlength="16" ng-model="NationalId">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 form-group form-item">
                        <label for="" class="ng-binding">ss</label>
                        <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control number ng-valid ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" maxlength="16" ng-model="PrincipleCode">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <div id="recaptcha01" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdpU8gZAAAAAO6-5k51vSLoNVV1Wmsc77S7ptlV"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe title="reCAPTCHA" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LdpU8gZAAAAAO6-5k51vSLoNVV1Wmsc77S7ptlV&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9vZmZpY2UzNjUuZW1pcy5nb3YuZWc6NDQz&amp;hl=ar&amp;v=rPvs0Nyx3sANE-ZHUN-0nM85&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=k31qvndf1wp5" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-g716ep6e9b8d" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea></div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 mt-3 text-center">
                        <button class="btn check-btn" ng-click="VerifyData()" ng-show="Loading == false">CHECK </button>
                        <img src="/wwwroot/images/loader.gif" width="60" ng-show="Loading == true" class="ng-hide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 text-center error-container ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="ErrorMessage !=''">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
           
        </div>
```

This is the code I am trying till now

```
.AddArgument "--disable-notifications"
.Start "Chrome"
.Get "https://office365.emis.gov.eg/"
.Wait 1000
.FindElementByXPath("//button[@ng-click='SetEmailType(1)']").Click
With .FindElementByXPath("//input[@ng-model='NationalId']")
    .Clear: .SendKeys shEF.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value
End With
With .FindElementByXPath("//input[@ng-model='PrincipleCode']")
    .Clear: .SendKeys shEF.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
End With
.SwitchToFrame .FindElementByTag("iframe", timeout:=10000)
.Wait 1000
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='recaptcha-anchor']").Click
.Wait 1000
```

On another page, there is a nother square for captcha to check and here's the outerhtml

```html
<div id="recaptcha02" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdpU8gZAAAAAO6-5k51vSLoNVV1Wmsc77S7ptlV"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe title="reCAPTCHA" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LdpU8gZAAAAAO6-5k51vSLoNVV1Wmsc77S7ptlV&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9vZmZpY2UzNjUuZW1pcy5nb3YuZWc6NDQz&amp;hl=ar&amp;v=rPvs0Nyx3sANE-ZHUN-0nM85&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=yb04gn21huf7" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-gmezfxiw48et" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-1" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea></div></div>
```

I couldn't check that square although I could do in a previous page

Comment: Is the website public? Always useful to mention this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the url `https://office365.emis.gov.eg/`. Click on the second button

Comment: When you get the error can you still find the element in the opened browser?

Comment: Yes I can find the element in the opened browser and that is very weird.

Comment: what about FindElementByCss("[ng-click='VerifyData()']")

Comment: I have tried using css and the same error too. Can you try on your side?

Comment: or `driver.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('[ng-click^=VerifyData]').click();"`

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this is working well on my side but take some time to load the next page. Thanks a lot

Comment: the ExecuteScript also works?

Comment: Yes it works too. I have updated  the question, there is another point (how to check the square of the captcha?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If this is unique `//div/button[@ng-click='VerifyData()']` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some `hardcoded delay` or `Explicit wait` and try again.
4. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

Switch to `defaultcontent`:

```
driver.SwitchToDefaultContent
```

Comment: Yes, it is unique and I have used Ctrl + F to make sure of the xpath.

Comment: and what about the 4 conditions that I have mentioned? I am getting `504 Gateway Time-out` at `https://office365.emis.gov.eg/` When I checked for `//div/button[@ng-click='VerifyData()']` XPath in the shared HTML, it is present `1/1` so we are good, but that's not entire page HTML.

Comment: I didn't find any iframes or shadow-root. The iframe exists before I check on the captcha square but after that, it disappeared.

Comment: You switched to iframe in your code and never switched to `default content` and since `//div/button[@ng-click='VerifyData()']` this is not in iframe, You are getting `NoSuchElement exception`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have thought of that but how can I switch back to the default content?

Comment: `driver.SwitchToDefaultContent` ?

Comment: Now it is working but the button disappeared and a gif appeared `Loading` and it takes a too long time and still loading. Is that related to the point I am clicking the captcha square using the code?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Please use explicit wait to click on the button or wait till it's clickable and then perform click using explicit waits.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't share a link to that page I can only guess.
So, instead of

```
//div/button[@ng-click='VerifyData()']
```

you can try using

```
//button[contains(@ng-click,'VerifyData')]
```